# Comparing more than one object properties in separate arrays

Tags: ruby

I am trying to figure out a way to iterate through and remove duplicate records from four different sources.

```
first_source = [#<Customer:0x007f911e307ad0 @id="123", @name="Whitehall">,#       <Customer:0x007f911e307ad0 @id="124", @name="Whitehall">#<Customer:0x007f911e307ad0 @id="125", @name="Whitehall">]
second_source =  [#<Customer:0x007f911e307ad0 @id="5000", @name="Whitehall">,#<Customer:0x007f911e307ad0 @id="5500", @name="Whitehall">#<Customer:0x007f911e307ad0 @id="123", @name="Whitehall">]
third_source =  [#<Customer:0x007f911e307ad0 @id="800", @name="Whitehall">,#<Customer:0x007f911e307ad0 @id="5000", @name="Whitehall">#<Customer:0x007f911e307ad0 @id="124", @name="Whitehall">]
fourth_source =  [#<Customer:0x007f911e307ad0 @id="4300", @name="Whitehall">,#<Customer:0x007f911e307ad0 @id="800", @name="Whitehall">#<Customer:0x007f911e307ad0 @id="125", @name="Whitehall">]
```

I tried

```
customers = []

dup_customers = first_source + second_source + third_source + fourth_source

dup_customers.combination(2).each do |cs1, cs2|
  customers << cs1 unless cs1.id != cs2.id
end
```

But this really did not work.

Can someone help me suggest a way/strategy for traversing through these four collections and finding the Customer id's that are equal and then doing something with it?

Comment: When there is a duplicate, do you want to remove it from both/all sources, or all but one, or none? Do you mean you want to detect rather than remove duplicates?

Comment: Also, to clarify: you consider two Customer objects to be duplicates if they have the same `id` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [Array#uniq](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq)?

```
customers = (first_source + second_source + third_source + fourth_source).uniq
```

`uniq` discards duplicates by element-wise comparison using [Object#eql?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F), so for this method to work, you would need to implement `Customer#eql?`.

```
class Customer
  def eql?(other)
    id == other.id #or however you define equality
  end
end
```

Comment: hey thanks for the quick response.. i tried that and it is not giving me back uniq results... i guess because the array is made up of Objects... and i need a way to loop through each in the array and come back with uniq results.

Comment: Awesome pje.. there is some sense in this now.. and you have put a few ideas in my head cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
dup_customers = 
[first_source, second_source, third_source, fourth_source]
.combination(2).flat_map{|s1, s2| s1 & s2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `eql` as @pje does is not necessary. `uniq` takes a block ([last example](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq)):

```
customers = [first_source ,second_source, third_source, fourth_source ].flatten
p customers.uniq{|c| c.id}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Array#|](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-7C) (union operator):

```
customers = first_source | second_source | third_source | fourth_source
```

It returns the result of the merging of the two arrays while removing duplicates:

```
 ["a", "b", "c" ] | [ "c", "d", "a" ]
 #=> [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
```

Comment: I'm rather confused, why the anonym downvote? (It certainly is an answer)